# Converting Expression to Func<Type, bool> in c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression

I'm working on a service base application. At the service side, I have to convert `Expression` to `Func<TypeOfEntity,bool>` for using in an EntityFramework query.

```
Type typeofEntity;// we just have type of entity and I could get it from entity name and assembly name
//ExpressionSerializer is in Serialize.Linq
ExpressionSerializer expressionSerializer = new ExpressionSerializer(new JsonSerializer());
Expression expr = expressionSerializer.DeserializeText(stringFromClient);//It's Ok until here
Func<?,bool> func = ?//How can I create Func of typeofEntity and bool
var result = Entities.Something.Where(func);
```

How can we convert `Expression` (not `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`) to `Func<T,bool>`?

Comment: What's the string you are deserializing? A lambda? What's the type of `expressionSerializer`?

Comment: "`Expression` (not `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`" -- That's not possible. `Expression` is an abstract class, you cannot possibly have an instance of that type. What is the concrete type you've got? (Check `expr.GetType()`.) If that's `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`, which does derive from `Expression`, an ordinary cast will work, so you can do `Entities.Something.Where((Expression<Func<T,bool>>)expr)`. Otherwise, what you can do depends on the actual type you're dealing with.

Comment: BTW, I overlooked it in my previous comment, but unless you have a really good reason to want `Func<T, bool>`, you should look to make sure you get `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, even if you don't already have that. `Entities.Something.Where(func)` will load all `Something`s, and process them on the client. `Entities.Something.Where(expr)` will construct an SQL query that lets the filtering happen on the server.

Comment: @hvd: We have type of entity that we should create `Func` for it. `Type typeofEntity` that we create it from Name of entity

Comment: @Mohammad Again, what's the concrete type you get? What does `expr.GetType()` return? Will it always be `Expression<Func<typeofEntity, bool>>` (invalid C#, but you know what I mean), or will it be some other `Expression` type?

Comment: @hvd: Got it. `expr.GetType()` return `{System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[System.Func2[Entity,System.Boolean]]}`

Comment: In that case, I agree with @qujck's suggestion to use `dynamic`, but not with `Compile()`. I would change that answer to have the function just do `return context.Where(expression);` (no `expression.Compile()`, but possibly do include `ToList()`, depending on your needs), and call it the same way he does.

Comment: @hvd: Thanks for the response. Can't we use `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` for creating `Func` of typeofEntity and bool?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43131/discussion-between-mohammad-and-hvd)

Comment: @hvd good spot - `Expression.Compile()` was superfluous and the result wasn't either used or required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dynamic` type to have `T` resolved at runtime. A class such as this

```
static class ExpressionRunner
{
    public static IList<T> Run<T>(
        Context context,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        where T : class
    {
        var result = context
            .Set<T>()
            .Where(expression);

        return result.ToList();
    }

}
```

Can run the `Expression` against the `Context`

```
Expression expr = expressionSerializer.DeserializeText(stringFromClient);
var result = ExpressionRunner.Run(Entities, expr as dynamic);
```

Note that the return type is also `dynamic` so it would be advisable to have this `Run` method at the top of the call chain to maximise performance - i.e. `Run` should return `void` and all the processing should be nested inside of `Run`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.But, Can't we use `Delegate.CreateDelegate()` for creating `Func` of typeofEntity and bool?

Comment: @Mohammad it's preferable to keep it as an `Expression` so that it executes against `IQueryable`. A `Func` will execute against `IEnumerable` which requires your `Context` to load the data from the database into memory.